# python3.8.10 source build with error [Makefile:617: sharedmods] Error 139

Tags: python, makefile

Wasted losts of time on build python3.8.10 source.

Build ENV:

```
gcc (GCC) 8.4.1 20200928 (Red Hat 8.4.1-1)

Linux localhost.localdomain 4.18.0-305.19.1.el8_4.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Sep 15 15:39:39 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux(centos8 x86_64)

File:./Objects/unicodeobject.c

Error:make: *** [Makefile:617: sharedmods] Error 139
```

Let me explain. In order to monitor what happens when connect two strings like this:

```
src_str = "hello "
dst_str = src_str + "world"
```

So, I inserted some extra code in `PyUnicode_Append` function and i hope this can help me store the parameter into file.

```
void
PyUnicode_Append_Handler(PyObject *left, PyObject *right)
{
    FILE* fp = fopen("/home/pyiast/append.log","a+");
    if (NULL == fp){
        return;
    }
    
    PyObject *data = PyUnicode_FromFormat("append:dst=%s, src=%s\n", PyUnicode_AsUTF8(left),PyUnicode_AsUTF8(right));
    if (data != NULL){
        PyObject_Print(data, fp, 0);
        Py_DECREF(data);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

void
PyUnicode_Append(PyObject **p_left, PyObject *right)
{
    //... other code
    assert(_PyUnicode_CheckConsistency(*p_left, 1));
    
    // this is my code
    PyUnicode_Append_Handler(left, right);
}
```

When re-make this code, the error occurs.

```
if test $? -ne 0 ; then \
        echo "generate-posix-vars failed" ; \
        rm -f ./pybuilddir.txt ; \
        exit 1 ; \
fi
 CC='gcc -pthread' LDSHARED='gcc -pthread -shared    ' OPT='-DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall'      _TCLTK_INCLUDES='' _TCLTK_LIBS=''       ./python -E ./setup.py  build
/bin/sh: line 9: 30341 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) CC='gcc -pthread' LDSHARED='gcc -pthread -shared    ' OPT='-DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall' _TCLTK_INCLUDES='' _TCLTK_LIBS='' ./python -E ./setup.py $quiet build
make: *** [Makefile:617: sharedmods] Error 139
```

If anyone has encountered this problem, please help me。

Comment: and there is an another problem.the ```PyUnicode_FromFomat``` can not format CRLF correct. the string "\n" has stored into file too, not lead a new line.

Comment: Well, something about the change you made is causing the Python executable to fail.  It's dumping a core, so you should use your debugger to debug that core file and you can see exactly what happened.

Comment: In your sample code in the `PyUnicode_Append()` function, you are using variables `left` and `right` but there's no indication as to what type these are or where they came from so we can't say if this is correct.

Comment: If you build the unmodified source with the same toolchain, in the same environment, then does the resulting Python pass all its tests?

Comment: Wouldn't `PyUnicode_FromFormat("append:dst=%U, src=%U\n", left, right);` be simpler, clearer, and more obviously correct (subject to the assumptions you're already making) than what you're currently using in `PyUnicode_Append_Handler()`?

Comment: @MadScientist Thanks for your advice, but it's a 'make' error,not a runtime error. so, i think it's not necessary to debug the core dump.

Comment: @JohnBollinger if build unmodified source, everything goes well.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I followed with your suggestion and reviewed my code. Yes ,you are right. I referenced a NULL object in my code. Now, the code can compile , but install procedure make an error. There is one thing i can't understand: it's shouldn't cause an 'make' or 'install'  error while compiling the code without syntax error.

Comment: @Hinghoi, Python's build and install processes use the built Python executable.  It is entirely possible for that executable to be built successfully but to fail at runtime.  In that case, later portions of the build or install process may fail.  You can consider that a built-in smoke test for the newly-built Python, if you like.

Comment: No, it's **not** a "make error".  The error "Error 139" is just make reporting to you that something went wrong in some command it tried to run.  The error you have to solve is whatever went wrong, and that's reported on the previous lines: "/bin/sh: line 9: 30341 Segmentation fault  (core dumped) ... ./python -E ./setup.py".  So the error that you have to solve is why the `./python` program you just built dumped core.  The best way to solve that is get out the debugger and look at the core that was dumped, as I said.  It seems that you have solved this, and now make doesn't report that error.